# Spring boot not finding Thymeleaf (messages) properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, properties-file

N.B. Before anyone says that this is a duplicate from [Spring Boot + Thymeleaf not finding message properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545667/spring-boot-thymeleaf-not-finding-message-properties) please know that I have tried to resolve my issue using the answers provided in the link but nothing has worked for me so far.

I'm running into a problem with using Thymeleaf and Spring Boot. I've followed the tutorial provided by Thymeleaf but for some reason when the template processing is finished, I end up with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h3>??admin.greeting_en??</h3>
    <p>??admin.deposit.request.accepted_en??</p>
    <p><strong>??email.generation_en??</strong></p>
    <p>??email.regards_en??</p>
    <p>??admin.regards_en??</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I placed my messages_en.properties under the module which contains the Spring configuration for Thymeleaf (template resolver, message resolver etc)... The path is notifications/src/main/resources/messages_en.properties

I have also placed the properties file inside the /templates directory and it still doesn't work.

The setup class for thymeleaf looks like this.

```
@Configuration
public class SpringMailConfig {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource emailMessageSource() {
        final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public TemplateEngine springTemplateEngine() {
        final SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver());
        templateEngine.setTemplateEngineMessageSource(emailMessageSource());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    private ITemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
        final ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        return templateResolver;
    }
}
```

As an example, inside my properties (messages_en.properties) file I have:

```
admin.greeting = Hello, Admin!
```

This is what the template looks like (the HTML file)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
    <h3 th:text="#{admin.greeting}">Dear Admin,</h3>
    <p th:text="#{admin.deposit.request.accepted(${amount}, ${user})}">The deposit request of AMOUNT euro made for user USER has been accepted.</p>
    <p><strong th:text="#{email.generation}">This is an automated email.</strong></p>
    <p th:text="#{email.regards}">Kind Regards,</p>
    <p th:text="#{admin.regards}">Robots</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing has worked and I can't figure out why. Using variables (denoted by the ${}) inside the templates works, but the messages (using the #{}) aren't found.

This is the class which I use to invoke the template engine. The method `String returnTemplateHtmlContent(String templatePath, Locale locale, Map<String, Object> map) throws TemplateInputException, NullPointerException` is the method which does the actual processing. The Locale passed is set to "en", the map holds variables to be inserted into the templates (this works).

```
public abstract class AbstractMailHelper {

    SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine;
    protected static final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";

    public AbstractMailHelper() {

    }

    public AbstractMailHelper(SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine) {
        this.springTemplateEngine = templateEngine;
    }

    //Prepares values to be injected into template
    protected Context prepareTemplateContext(Locale locale, Map<String, Object> contextMap) {
        final Context context = new Context(locale);
        context.setVariables(contextMap);
        return context;
    }

    //returns as a string the template with the custom values inserted
    protected String returnTemplateHtmlContent(String templatePath, Locale locale, Map<String, Object> map) throws TemplateInputException, NullPointerException {
        return springTemplateEngine.process(templatePath, prepareTemplateContext(locale, map));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you're invoking the engine?

Comment: Where is the template located?under /templates?

Comment: The respective templates are located under /templates/admin. I tried placing the properties file inside /templates/admin as well but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm in the same situation.