# UTF-8 encoding issue with Thymeleaf Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, utf-8, thymeleaf, tomcat9

I have issue with UTF-8 characters. I've tried many solutions, but nothing is working for me. What I have right now:

- Tomcat (server.xml):

  ```xml
  <Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" useBodyEncodingForURI="true" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
  ```
- Base configuration class:

  ```java
  public class HomeInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] { WebSecurityConfig.class };
  }
  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      return new Class[] { WebMvcConfiguration.class };
  }
  @Override
  protected String[] getServletMappings() {
      return new String[] { "/" };
  }
  @Override
  protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
      CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
      filter.setEncoding("UTF-8"); // forcing UTF-8
      filter.setForceEncoding(true);
      return new Filter[] { filter };
  }
  }
  ```
- WebMvcConfiguration class which contains Thymeleaf configuration:

  ```java
  @Bean
  public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
      ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
      viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
      viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // forcing UTF-8
      viewResolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
      viewResolver.setOrder(1);
      viewResolver.setViewNames(new String[] { ".html", ".xhtml" });
      return viewResolver;
  }
  @Bean
  public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
      SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
      templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // forcing UTF-8
      templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
      templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
      templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
      templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
      templateResolver.setCacheable(true);
      return templateResolver;
  }
  @Bean
  public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
      SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
      templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
      templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
      return templateEngine;
  }
  @Override
  public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
      ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
      resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
      registry.viewResolver(resolver);
  }
  ```
- WebSecurityConfig which contains the rest of the configuration:

  ```java
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().anonymous().antMatchers("/login**", "/*.js", "/*.css", "/*.svg").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
                      .antMatchers("/login**").permitAll().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("username")
                      .passwordParameter("password").defaultSuccessUrl("/", true).permitAll().and().logout()
                      .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                      .invalidateHttpSession(true).permitAll();
      CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
      filter.setEncoding("UTF-8"); // another forcing UTF-8
      filter.setForceEncoding(true);
      http.addFilterBefore(filter, CsrfFilter.class);
  }
  ```
- all html pages contain:

  ```html
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
  ```
- before I've added Thymeleaf and used `jsp` I've been able to display special characters
- also checked that all files (`.html`) are encoded with UTF-8
- Eclipse settings changed to keep everything in UTF-8
- checked probably all answers on stackoverflow related to this issue and verified all higher ranked answers (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33048628/spring-mvc-with-thymeleaf-and-tomcat-8-utf-8-encoding-issue), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863489/characterencodingfilter-dont-work-together-with-spring-security-3-2-0/23051264#23051264) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28112852/springboot-utf-8-doesnt-work-in-messages-properties))
- checked Thymeleaf messaging solution ([some stack question for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545667/spring-boot-thymeleaf-not-finding-message-properties))
- escaped characters `\u0119` are displayed as they are - `\u0119`
- created new project with same `pom.xml`, Spring/Thymeleaf configuration

And **still** instead of polish
    `ąęłźżńłó`
I have 
    `???????ó`
displayed on page. Any ideas?

Unfortunatelly I don't have
    `web.xml`
and whole configuration uses annotations. <s>I can't control
    `Filter`
classes order</s> - see [can use @Order annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter)

Used technologies: Spring Framework 5.1.6, Spring Security 5.1.5, Thymeleaf 3.0.11, Thymeleaf Spring security4 3.0.4, Maven 4, Tomcat 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly I have to answer my own question.

To read UTF-8 data from properties file, just use encoding property

```java
@Component
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:config/data.properties", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

basically what helped was adding some additional method calls to the `configureViewResolvers` method:

```java
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // <- this was added
        resolver.setForceContentType(true); // <- this was added
        resolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8"); // <- this was added
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
```

and additionaly in `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method I've changed the way how filter is added to this:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        filter.setForceEncoding(true);

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().anonymous()
        .antMatchers("/login**", "/*.js", "/*.css", "/*.svg" ).permitAll()
        // ... some other config
        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(filter, CsrfFilter.class); // <- this was added
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So this might seem very remedial, but have you navigated to the directory structure, right clicked the folder containing your pages, and selecting refresh?

I don't know what IDE you're using, but in the past I have had to manually go into Eclipse and refresh the package containing the static content.

If you don't do this, it won't pick up on the changes.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0), and refreshing doesn't help neither.